# Tooltip for keywords in a pre formatted text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, tooltip

I am using angular to get pre-formatted text and print it in a web page. My objective is to add a javascript / jquery function to search keywords in the text and add tooltips for those keywords from a database or json or xml file. Is there any jquery or angular package to do this?How can i do this?

Comment: You are not supposed to use angular with any other DOM manipulation library, it will cost performance issues.

Comment: Did you mean tooltip or autocomplete ?

Comment: i mean tooltip to display the help info for certain keywords on mouse over

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like angular material  / ng-bootstrap it comes with tooltip directive.

If not you can use the library like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tooltip-directive)

Searching "Angular tooltip" on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) will give you a few more options as well.

For dynamically getting data from the server, you can use angular's built-in [HTTP](https://angular.io/guide/http) module.

Add a `(change)` event (preferably with denounce function) to the input, and fetch data based on on the input text.

Comment: i want add tooltips dynamically like reading keywords and values from a db and replacing keywords in the text in page.

Comment: That should be another question then.